# I keep getting this error. The requested URL could not be matched by routing

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I am trying to route to the **edit** action of my controller but I have not been successful. Below is the content of my **module.config.php** file. I am working with Zend framework 2. Do I need to route every action in my controller?

```
<?php
 return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Manager\Controller\Index' => 'Manager\Controller\IndexController',
    ),
),
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'manager' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                // Change this to something specific to your module
                'route'    => '/manager',
                'defaults' => array(
                    // Change this value to reflect the namespace in which
                    // the controllers for your module are found
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Manager\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                // This route is a sane default when developing a module;
                // as you solidify the routes for your module, however,
                // you may want to remove it and replace it with more
                // specific routes.
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'Manager' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),

);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are new, there are few things you need to know if you are working on application for some CRUD, i will recommend that you must create a new module, as guided in ZF2 Skeleton app or Album app, Settings that you provided are correct and have nothing wrong.

Lets assume you already created a new module and you are working on new module, and all your routes are defined properly what you must do is include name of your Module to application.config.php file, this file is under config folder, If you already created a bew module then add its name in this section

```
     'modules' => array(
    'ZendDeveloperTools',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',
    'Application,
     'newlyCreatedModule'

      ),
```

Above is a part of snipppet from 1 of my files so dont be confused with it. For more refrence try to follow Album Application for ZF2.
Also you dont need to write routes in any controller its handled by ZF2, in module.config.php file which we have to provide for every module.

Comment: I have done that already. The URL app.localhost/manager works, but when I try to app.localhost/manager/edit I get the above stated error

Comment: Again, i am telling you to create new module, for Edit, ADD etc

Comment: public function editAction() {
  $form = new ManagerForm();
  $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
  return $viewModel;

 }

Comment: Does this mean that I have to create a module for every action I want to create, why cant they all be in the same controller?

Comment: Your code is correct, what you need to understand is ZF2, ZF2 handles things in its own way, AND NO you dont need to create module for every action.
 if you want to create a controller that handles all manager related actions, you need to create a new MODULE, DEFAULT module which is APPLICATION module is only for Default puposes.

Comment: Default Module loads every other module in it, Its like a container where every other module is loaded, so this is also 1 of reason why default module isnt touched generally

Comment: Yes I did that I called it the Manager module

Comment: if you created a new module and named it manager then routes defined in its module.config.php need to be slighlty different then that of Application module, code that you posted is copy of Application module, Also REMMEBER in ZF2 every ACTION must have its VIEW file too, in your case you must create edit.phtml

Comment: I made some changes in the module.config.php My controller however, is called IndexController that is why it is written as such in the module.config.php file

Comment: 'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]' replace this with 
 'route'    => '[/:controller[/:action]]', and see if it works

Comment: Now I get a slightly different error saying The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.

Controller:
Manager\Controller\Edit(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: Manager\Controller\Edit)

Comment: this means you cannot have 2 index controllers, change name of your controller and change it in other files too.

Comment: I changed the name of the controller to ManagerController.php, I also changed the class name I still get the same error  The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class. Controller: Manager\Controller\Edit(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: Manager\Controller\Edit)

Comment: Could I send the entire module to you?

Comment: did you changed that in module.config.php too?Sure you can sed but i don have much time so hurry up

Comment: Please could u give me ur email address so I send it to you

Answer (score 0):

Actions can be routed in your controller with [/:action] as part of the route. This will get mapped to a function in the Controller matching the same name, eg in your example ../manager/foo will be mapped to the fooAction function, ..manager/index will be mapped to to the indexAction function etc

Usually (at least in the examples I have seen) the ID of the record to edit is passed as a parameter in the url. eg. example.com/manager/edit/1

If this is what you want to achieve you are missing a piece from your route "[/:id]" (see code below)

Try this as a simplified version for your router (module.config.php)

```
<?php
namespace Manager;
return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Manager\Controller\Index' => 'Manager\Controller\IndexController',
    ),
),
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'manager' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/manager[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id' => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Manager\Controller\Index',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
'template_path_stack' => array(
    'Manager' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
  ),

);
```

Also make sure you have an edit function in your IndexController Class "IndexController.php" eg

```
public function editAction()
{

//Some code to edit the record....

}
```

and an "edit.phtml" file in your view directory

Answer (score 0):

The way you set up your Route is the following:

```
/manager[/:controller[/:action]]
```

This means, the url you would look for probably is:

```
/manager/manager/edit
```

You need to understand that a child-route is nothing more but an appendix to the current route definitions. So what you could do is what @Finbarr suggested or you go with nested routes who are a little faster and would look like this:

```
'manager' => array(
    'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Http\Literal',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/manager',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Manager\Controller\Index',
            'action'     => 'index'
        )
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes'  => array(
        'add' => array(
            'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/add'
            ),
            'defaults' => array(
                'action' => 'add',
            ),
        ),
        'edit' => array(
            'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Http\Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/edit[/:id]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'action' => 'edit',
                ),
                'constraints' => array(
                    'id' => '\d+',
                ),
            )
        ),
    )
)
```

Notice the difference in what is done. Both the routes `manager` and `add` are of type `Literal`. This means that those urls never have any parameter attached. They can always have `QueryParameters`, but `RouteParameters` won't work on them.

And then you get your `edit`-Route. This one now is of type `Segment`, meaning that there is a part, a segment, that is variable. Furthermore the route is prepended by `/edit`, so the full url now becomes at least `/manager/edit` with the optional id `/manager/edit[/1234]`. It is up to you to have the ID optional or not. If you don't want it optional, simply remove the brackets around it and create the route definition like this: `'route' => '/edit/:id'`, though personally i like having an 'edit-index' if no ID is attached.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I finally got it to work. My code in module.config.php is exactly like what is provided in Finbarr's answer. Here it is again.

```
namespace Manager;
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Manager\Controller\Manager' => 'Manager\Controller\ManagerController',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'manager' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/manager[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Manager\Controller\Manager',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'manager' => DIR . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```